# Eloquent query, combine where and whereBetween

Tags: eloquent

Is there any wrong with this eloquent query? I want to use a where and wherebetween. I dont get any items in return.

```
$start_date = "2021-02-1-01";
$end_date = "2021-02-28";
$date_array = array($start_date, $end_date);
$data = array(
       'project_id' => $project_id,
);

 return WasteDataModel::where($data)
  ->where(function ($query) use($date_array) {
      return $query->whereBetween('date', $date_array);
  })->get();
```

I have tried this aswell

```
return WasteDataModel::where($data)->whereBetween('date', $date_array)->get();
```

with no return

Comment: double check your date column on database, if its `date` coumn or `datetime/timestamp`

Comment: if its `datetime/timestamp` then you need to compare only date by using 
->whereBetween('DATE(date)', $date_array)

Comment: and your start date is incorrect `$start_date = "2021-02-1-01";`
it should be ``$start_date = "2021-02-01";``

Comment: "date" : ISODate("2021-02-15T22:35:20.202Z") this is the field. Iam using mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATE` method of MYSQL with `DB::raw()` to compare dates only

```
return WasteDataModel::where($data)
       ->whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE(date)'),  $date_array)
       ->get();
```